# Behat/Symfony 3 - How to check if a user is logged in

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I'm using behat and Symfony 3 and I want to create a context to check if a user has logged in, like this:

```
public function __construct(
        UserManagerInterface $userManager,
        AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker,
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
    ) {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

/**
     * @param string $user
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @Then /^I should be login as "([^"]*)" with the role "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function iShouldBeLoggedInAsWithTheRole(string $user, string $role): void
    {
        $loggedUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUsername();
        var_dump($loggedUser);

        Assert::same(
            $loggedUser,
            $user,
            "The logged user is $loggedUser, expected $user"
        );

        Assert::true(
            $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($role),
            "The user $user must have the role $role"
        );
    }
```

And these are the steps. The first one fails, running the step I defined in the context. The second one works, that steps goes to the user profile page and checks if the email of the user is in the page, which does.

That can only happen if the login has been correctly done.

So the problem seems to be the token storage in the user context, any idea why this happens?

```
Scenario: Log in with username and password
    Given I am on "/login"
    When I fill in the following:
      | username | jsmith@domain.com |
      | password | 1234              |
    And I press "_submit"
    And I am on "/"
    Then I should be login as "jsmith@domain.com" with the role "ROLE_USER"
      The logged user is anon., expected jsmith@domain.com (InvalidArgumentException)

  Scenario: Log in with username and password
    Given I am on "/login"
    When I fill in the following:
      | username | jsmith@domain.com |
      | password | 1234              |
    And I press "_submit"
    And I am on "/profile"
    Then I should see "jsmith@domain.com"
```

And this is the behat configuration

```
default:
    formatters:
        pretty:
            verbose: true
            paths: false
            snippets: false

    extensions:

        Behat\MinkExtension:
               base_url: 'https://localhost/app_dev.php/'
               sessions:
                  default:
                      symfony2: ~

        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true

        FriendsOfBehat\CrossContainerExtension: ~

        FriendsOfBehat\PerformanceExtension: ~

        FriendsOfBehat\VariadicExtension: ~

    gherkin:
        filters:
            tags: "~@todo && ~@cli" # CLI is excluded as it registers an error handler that mutes fatal errors
```

Comment: are those scenarios involving UI with WebDriver, or selenium or something like this? Or are them running without any "browser" facility?

Comment: @DonCallisto without any browser facility, I added the behat config to the question

Answer (score 0):

You are logging through a "simulated browser page"

```
Given I am on "/login"
  When I fill in the following:
    | username | jsmith@domain.com |
    | password | 1234              |
  And I press "_submit"
```

that is a process totally independent of behat process  where you're trying to retrieve logged user.

Only thing that you could do, is to redefine login step, query explicitly the db, save in a kind of [shared context](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/558) these user, and check it after (but at that point, this test, seems to be pretty useless)